How to disable "Tools ->“actions on save” ->"Reformat code" option?
With PphStorm 2024.1 ( Build #PS-241.14494.237, built on March 27, 2024 ) on any saving of a current page I
see dialog “Reformat code” => “Processing”, which takes some time to process, especially on big pages.
I check that menu option Tools ->“actions on save” ->Reformat code If OFF :

Actually I got this problem after I set this option ON  and after some work I disliked it and set off , but that did
work...
How can I disable it ?

Probably that dialog is displayed incorrectly.
Notice the time on your system clock when you see it again, open your log (Help | Open log in Editor) and filter the events by the time noticed. What do you see?
